# how to calculate offset.left position to display image on link hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function that when a user does a mouse-over a thumbnail, a larger preview of the image pops up. The JavaScript calculates the top and left offset position to either display the preview on the right or left of the screen, depending on the screen size.

The function works when the object passed is an image.

My goal is to use the same function as a template, and have it work but instead that using a thumbnail for the hover event, just use a link. So the user does a mouse over the link, and the image preview pops up.

My problem is that the offset left position is not being calculated when using IE8 or IE11, Firefox and Chrome work fine.

The image is always being displayed on the right size of the screen. But this only happens on IE. I guess, I am not sure, but perhaps IE treats the  and  tag differently to calculate offset?

Here is a copy of the jquery function:

```
function linkOverShow(a, strSKU) {

$("#pUpImg").attr("src", "/images/items/" + strSKU + ".jpg");
var offset = $(a).offset();
if (offset.left - 350 < 0) {
    $('#pUp').css('top', (offset.top - 125)).css('left', (offset.left + 100));
} else {
    $('#pUp').css('top', (offset.top - 125)).css('left', (offset.left - 350));
}
$("#pUp").show();
```

}

On IE, the code only goes to the line:

```
 $('#pUp').css('top', (offset.top - 125)).css('left', (offset.left + 100));
```

I am hoping to fins someone in this forum that can offer some ideas as to why this is happening, and possibly offer some recommendations to try to solve the issue.

I hope also I am asking this question correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you much.

Comment: How exactly off are they? A few pixels or millions and millions off?
To test you should use the console and output it in there `$('#pUp').offset();`

Comment: When I use firebug on FF offset.left has 351.5.When in IE using the developer tools, offset.let contains 349 which makes the image be displayed 449 pixels to the right. This is when using a 1680x1050 monitor.

Comment: Yep, this is sadly because the browsers handle elements different. So `line-height: 10px` will come out slightly differently on FF/Chrome to what IE does. Welcome to developing. My suggest, make sure you have a reset file in your CSS

Comment: Hi Jamie, thank you for your reply. I am not sure what is a reset CSS file. Yes dealing with browser compatibility is a bit frustrating at times.

Comment: This might help :) http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: I don't think I can go this route. I think I will have to keep tweaking the function the route to go. Thank you for the recommendation though.